# Drupal Ajax form submit form click twice

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal

Wierd scenario.

The Ajax form that I have created works fine but only on a second click of the submit button. This is happening on a specific environment. It works fine on some other environments. I do not understand why its making the ajax call and going into validate function on second click of the button.

On the first click it just shows the throbber Please wait... and then no validation message.

```
 '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'form_get',
    'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'progress' => array(),
),
```

I am not aware of what parameter in the environment would cause this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for debugging things like this. If you get it set up and running, you will be able to see the AJAX requests and responses when you click the button. Then it will just be a case of figuring out what the difference is between the first and second request.

The issue sounds like it is probably something javascript related anyway, so keep a close eye on your browser console.